# Continuously compile/watch source files in ConTEXt?

Tags: context, latexmk

Is there an equivalent to [latexmk](http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/) in Context?
I want the script to watch my source files for changes and continuously recompile them.

Here is how I would do it with latexmk:

```
latexmk -bibtex -pdf -pvc document.tex
```

*EDIT*: I am on windows. Preferably this should be cross-platform (just like Context :-)

Comment: Try the [atchange](http://schneider.ncifcrf.gov/atchange.html) program that is written in Perl and would work on Windows as well.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know latexmk, but if you just want to trigger a new ConTeXt run if you
modify the source file you can use
[inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) (assuming you use Linux). This
mechanism is not ConTeXt related. Here's a simple example watching the file
`somefile.tex`.

```
file='somefile.tex'
while inotifywait --event modify "$file"; do
  context --batchmode "$file"
done
```

You can also watch an entire directory tree, for instance if you use a [project
structure](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Project_structure).

*Edit:* On MacOS and other BSDs the [kqueue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue)
mechanism provides a similar functionality.

Comment: OSX also has [filesystem events](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: No I am on windows :-(